# Freemarker doesn't print html content

Tags: jakarta-ee, freemarker

I begin some Freemarker code but I have a problem.

Let's say that my FTL is like the following:

```
<#list datas as x>
Name : ${x.name}
< /#list>
```

In Eclipse console I have the correct result but nothing is printing in my browser. I have the HTML Template but nothing between my BODY.

Do you know what's going wrong ?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What `Writer` are you passing to `Template.process`? You should pass the `Writer` of the `HttpResponse` to it, or something that eventually writes its input there. If auto-flushing was explicitly disabled in FreeMarker (it probably wasn't anyway) and you don't call flush on the `Writer`, that can also lead to issues like this.

Also, be sure `datas` is not empty, because then the above template outputs nothing.

What prints the HTML body tags anyway? Is that not FreeMarker?

Comment: I have all the HTML Template when I'm displaying the source of my browser's page.